# ListView creates cells for every single letter of a string array in Xamarin

Tags: c#, arrays, string, listview, xamarin

I am facing the problem, that my ListView Page does not display each element of my `string[]` but separates every item of my array so that every cell contains one letter of the word.
Instead of "Maria" the outcome is
"M
a r i a" each in different cells.

My auto-generated XAML code:

```
<ListView x:Name="schuelerListe"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">

<!--Built in Cells-->
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextCell Text="{Binding .}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

My xaml.cs code

```
public Wuensche1(string[] girlsSplit, string[] boysSplit, int boysLength, int girlsLength, string text1, string text2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var _girlsSplit = girlsSplit;
        var _boysSplit = boysSplit;


        schuelerListe.ItemsSource = _girlsSplit;
        //for (int i = 0; i < girlsLength; i++)
        //{
        // schuelerListe.ItemsSource.Add(_girlsSplit[i]);
        //};
```

`boysSplit[]` and `girlsSplit[]` are the result of the string `text1` and `text2` being seperated after every comma which are all passed via the constructor.

**EDIT**

The code that is used for the names:

```
char[] charsToTrim = { ' ' };
private void NamesBoys_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        text1 = ((Editor)sender).Text;
        boysSplit = text1.Split(',');
        jungs.Text = text1;
        boysLength = boysSplit.Length;
    }

    private void NamesGirls_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        text2 = ((Editor)sender).Text;
        text2.Trim(charsToTrim);
        girlsSplit = text2.Split(',');
        maedels.Text = girlsSplit[0] + "\n" + girlsSplit[1];
        girlsLength = girlsSplit.Length;
    }
```

Comment: What is the outcome if you provide several names?

Comment: Unfortunately I already provide several names, but it only displays one of them (and this one is split up)

Comment: You should post in the question the part of the code that is critical to your problem, that's the part where you split the strings.

Comment: When do you call `Wuensche1`? Also, did you try debugging and verifying the value of `girlsSplit` inside this method?

Comment: please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Alright, Wuensche1 is the class (or here: page) which is called after I press a button that also passes the arguments to the constructor of Wuensche1. `girlsSplit` appears to be null, but I can still get each element of it on the page Wuensche1. The length of the arrays is 5 which is also correct

Comment: @Bizhan I didn't know where the error is sourced so I hoped it was already in the code I provided

Comment: I get it. but please keep in mind that stackoverflow is not a debugging service. A question is useful (to the website and to the future users) only if it's asked clearly and correctly and if the problem is reproducible using the provided information and source code.

Comment: Even if I put the unformatted string of the editor ("Paul, Papa, Martin, Leo, Leon")   `schuelerliste.ItemsSource = text1` the listView puts every character into a single cell

Comment: you've set ItemsSource twice. `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"` will get overwritten by `schuelerListe.ItemsSource = _girlsSplit;` and clearly the rest of the XAML won't split the characters by itself. so you need to debug your code to see how are you modifying the strings. e.g. put a breakpoint on `schuelerListe.ItemsSource = _girlsSplit;`

Comment: moreover, I believe changing `ItemsSource` in code is not a good practice. e.g. if the reference of the _girlsSplit is the same (but you just change a few elements) the collection will not get updated automatically. so either use the binding with a notifyable approach (INotifyCollectionChanged) or make sure the ItemsSource is reset to null before set to an object. but none of these will help you with the error unless you show us the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for that advice with `ItemsSource`, it is actually helpful for my upcoming questions. Yet I don't know what else to show you in my code. Both methods in which the strings are formatted (just split after every comma and the not working trimming of spaces) are provided, so is the code that uses the strings to display it in a ListView.
The names are split up correctly, when I print them to the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution:

The listView apparently has problems with displaying string arrays. What you can do is just convert the `string` into a `List`.
e.g:

```
List<string> yourList = yourString.ToList(); 

        listView.ItemsSource = yourList;
```